# Recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed?

Tags: kernel, compiling, qemu, raspberrypi

I'm attempting to build a kernel for QEMU to emulate a raspberry pi:
http://xecdesign.com/compiling-a-kernel/
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

However, running the command:
make ARCH=arm

it compiled well for a good long while, but then halted when it got this message:

```
kevin@kevin-laptop:~/linux$ make ARCH=arm
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CHK     kernel/config_data.h
  LINK    vmlinux
  LD      vmlinux.o
  MODPOST vmlinux.o
  GEN     .version
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
drivers/built-in.o: In function `mmc_fixup_device':
of_iommu.c:(.text+0xb9674): undefined reference to `mmc_debug'
Makefile:923: recipe for target 'vmlinux' failed
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

I'm not exactly sure what it's telling me.  My guess is that it cannot find a library that it needs in it's compilation.  I'm using the raspberry pi toolkit (Which seems like it should be plug and play essentially if they have it up on their git for the official Pi toolchain)

Any help?

Comment: What is your ubuntu version ? I had no problem cross-compiling on **ubuntu 15.04** with *gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64* from raspberrypi repo, using the command `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -j 3`. May be add `CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -j 3` to your make command ?

Comment: I've also got this issue building on gentoo using crossdev and specifying the whole path in the CROSS_COMPILE variable, so it's not just ubuntu...

Answer (score 3):

add below driver to the file (arch/arm/configs/bcm2835_defconfig)

```
 CONFIG_MMC_BCM2835=y
 CONFIG_MMC_BCM2835_DMA=y
 CONFIG_DMADEVICES=y
 CONFIG_DMA_BCM2708=y

cp arch/arm/configs/bcm2835_defconfig ./.config
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- menuconfig
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-
```

it works for me.

that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem using the Debian jessie cross toolchain. Using rpi-3.18.y kernel. Traced it down to `mmc_debug` that was improperly defined:

```
christoph@debian:~/raspidev/linux$ find drivers/mmc -name \*.c -exec -H grep mmc_debug {} \;
drivers/mmc/host/bcm2835-mmc.c
drivers/mmc/host/omap_hsmmc.c
drivers/mmc/core/quirks.c
```

Looking further, only the `bcm2835-mmc.c` and `quirks.c` have the symbol defined:

```
bcm2835-mmc.c:
/*static */unsigned mmc_debug;
/*static */unsigned mmc_debug2;
module_param(mmc_debug, uint, 0644);
module_param(mmc_debug2, uint, 0644);

quirks.c:
extern unsigned mmc_debug;
```

So I went back and enabled BOTH the MMC drivers as well as the BCM2835 host adapter in my configuration. This ADDED to the config patch already applied.

```
diff --git a/drivers/mmc/host/Kconfig b/drivers/mmc/host/Kconfig
index 3e7abcd..95eb332 100644
--- a/drivers/mmc/host/Kconfig
+++ b/drivers/mmc/host/Kconfig
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@ comment "MMC/SD/SDIO Host Controller Drivers"

 config MMC_BCM2835
        tristate "MMC support on BCM2835"
-       depends on MACH_BCM2708 || MACH_BCM2709 || ARCH_BCM2835
+       depends on MACH_BCM2708 || MACH_BCM2709 || ARCH_BCM2835 || ARCH_VERSATILE_PB || ARCH_VERSATILE_AB
        help
          This selects the MMC Interface on BCM2835.
```

Then activate the BCM2835 in the config and compile. Worked for me.

Comment: :o) I followed https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel/wiki and ran into this problem with 4.1.18. Adding `|| ARCH_VERSATILE_PB || ARCH_VERSATILE_AB` to drivers/mmc/host/Kconfig and then in menuconfig selecting the mmc BCM2835 driver got me through it.